# How to explain chain of logical facts creation of inference engine

Tags: artificial-intelligence, expert-system

I made expert system by means of clips library. 
I have an issue to explain results of expert system work.

The rules is simple as possible and look like "if a is not operable then b is not operable". 
I implemented a kind of revert logic inference engine with plain rules and facts system.

And to accurate the question, are there concrete approaches of getting explanation in `CLIPS` expert system.

Comment: That's so broad and ambiguous. Do you need to present the results or are you having trouble understanding why it does what it does? In the first case, take a look at some scientific papers and how the authors go about structuring them. In the latter case, use print statements or debugger to see what's going on or, post some of the results here and say what you are expecting instead.

Comment: Yes, I want to understand why result of inference is so. Prints are good, but it's only for me. I want to tell user what is going on, what the reasons of such a situation. Thanks for advice about papers, could you give me concrete links, I'll be grateful. And to accurate the question, are there concrete approaches of getting explanation in `CLIPS` expert system. Thanks!

Comment: I need not theoretical, but practical advice

Comment: OK, here is one, http://www.jatit.org/volumes/research-papers/Vol4No10/5Vol4No10.pdf. All I did was Google for "artificial intelligence papers clips expert system". Practical advice is the more you know your subject the better you can explain it :)

Comment: Thanks! It's just not wanted to reinvent the wheel...